# SQL XML column filtered by partial XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Is it possible to filter a XML column, by matching a partial XML?

Examples:

My XML column for a given record might have:

```
<element1>
  <subelement1>value1</subelement1>
  <subelement2>value2</subelement2>
  <subelement3>value3</subelement3>
</element1>
```

And I have the following partial XML to be used as a filter:

```
<element1>
  <subelement2>value2</subelement2>
  <subelement3>value3</subelement3>
</element1>
```

In this case, since both elements and their values match the ones in the record, it should return the record.

However, in the partial XML below, it's not a match, since `subelement4` is not present in the XML column for this given record:

```
<element1>
  <subelement2>value2</subelement2>
  <subelement4>value4</subelement4>
</element1>
```

In the same line, what's the recommended way of filtering a XML column using multiple elements? The examples I see are always filtering one element, not multiple.

My current solution is a comma separated value string that I split into a table with 2 columns (element name and value) and cross apply. It works well. I'm just wondering if there is something better out there. I was thinking about sending a partial XML string and, somehow (this question), match this partial XML with the XML column.

Comment: Can you explain why the first XML is a match, but the third is not? Both contain elements that don't exist in the filter. Perhaps you mean "the XML that contains all the elements in the filter AND matching their values in the filter, should be returned"?

Comment: @ZoffDino Thank you, I edited. Yes, value should be taken into consideration as well, not just the element name. There is no third. The first XML is the one in the database. The second is the XML filter as a match (example). The third is the XML filter as a no match (example).

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely clear on what you are trying to do. I think the code below gives you some guidance. If you'll clarify your question I can try to be more thorough.

```
declare @x1   [xml] =N'<element1>
<subelement1>value1</subelement1>
<subelement2>value2</subelement2>
<subelement3>value3</subelement3>
</element1>'
    , @x2 [xml] = N'<element1>
<subelement2>value2</subelement2>
<subelement3>value3</subelement3>
</element1>'
    , @x3 [xml] = N'<element1>
<subelement2>value2</subelement2>
<subelement4>value4</subelement4>
</element1>';
--
select t.c.query(N'.')
   , t.c.value(N'(./text())[1]'
               , N'[sysname]')
from   @x1.nodes(N'/*/*') as t(c)
where  t.c.value(N'(./text())[1]'
             , N'[sysname]') = N'value2';
--
select t.c.query(N'.')
   , t.c.value(N'(./text())[1]'
               , N'[sysname]')
from   @x1.nodes(N'/*/*') as t(c)
where  t.c.exist(N'//*[local-name()="subelement4"]') = 1;
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid. I don't want to specify the elements in the query, they will vary. I want to use the input (partial XML) as a filter to retrieve the records, getting only the records where all elements and their values in this partial XML exists in the XML column.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do that. It's something I've needed to do on occasion as well. The work around is to shred each stack into a table and perform an EXCEPT. Ugly, but it works.